# Deploying python based algorithms/ code on SPARK

Tags: apache-spark, deployment, pyspark

**Question**
***How would you run Python/ pyspark custom algorithms/ code on SPARK which need to be executed in n time intervals.*** 
sub-questions:

1. How to deal with python/ pyspark module dependencies for each deployment?
2. How to organizationally deal with deployments on SPARK -> please share how you currently deal with this in your production environment.
3. How to execute in a high-availability setting each algorithm at N intervals? -> avoiding single machine dependencies as with cron jobs

**Context**
We invest heavily in the development of ML algos. Typically we have been running these on SPARK which integrates with our data pipeline. However, now that we are increasing the number of dev teams that work on this, we are facing few constraints. 
Typically one could use a CD (continuous delivery) approach such as [go.cd](https://www.thoughtworks.com/go/) or [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) or similar.  However, with SPARK, as far as I'm aware of, the python/ pyspark modules that you can use are configured for each slave/ node. Normally we would opt for a python virtual environment to solve dependency issues but this seems out of the question. So far we considered running dockers/ virtual machines with a fully configured node but wonder if there aren't better solutions out there.

The last part really comes down to job execution. Our algo's are just a bunch of code that extract data, do something with it, and export an output for further processing elsewhere. Currently we are using a crontab to do this but this is not really useful for high availability clusters; your cron jobs are constrained to a single machine and not to the cluster so if this node goes down...
According to this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375571/running-scheduled-spark-job), SPARK did not yet support jobs. A few alternatives were offered such as [Azkaban](https://azkaban.github.io/) or [Pinball](https://github.com/pinterest/pinball) yet I'm curious what you use in your production environments today (original thread dates back to 2015).

Comment: I came here looking for the same regarding deployment. I think dockerize is a good solution, much more than virtualenv. You might then have multiple spark clusters as a sea of containers in your physical cluster though, not really sure. As for the scheduling, have a look at Apache (incubating) Airflow. It's all python, DAGs and has some great web UI, logging, backfilling, retries, all the scaffolding for ETL, which is effectively what you are doing. Cron + bash is caveman! Time scheduling is also not ideal, you want sensors to detect file arrival or data change and task dependency pipelines.