# schedule spark job in spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark-scala script I am running in spark-shell

```
spark2-shell -i test.scala
```

It works fine. Any suggestions on how I can schedule this script to run every hour could be helpful.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375571/running-scheduled-spark-job

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is not spark related since there is no built in mechanism for that.

You can actually consider using a cron like this

```
0 * * * * spark2-shell -i test.scala
```

or you might also want to use oozie, which is a bit more complex, but a lot easier to maintain if you have a lot of spark job to run

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/index.html