# Run a spark command automatically

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have an object in spark scala that reads an HDFS file and export it in a local file, within my cluster. I created the function, with an object, I created a SparkSession and the function correctly returns what I want with the following command:

```
ReadFiles.main(Array("hdfs://.../info.log"))
```

But I wanted this function to run every 5 minutes. Is there a way to execute the command every 5 minutes? Or else create some variable in SparkSession function that does?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running scheduled Spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375571/running-scheduled-spark-job)

Comment: @andreoss I think the question is the same, but I'm new to spark scala and I can't follow those rules ... Where do I put the time I want it to run? What do I put in CLASS, MASTER and ARGS? Where do I run the wrapper script? How to create crontab? How do I add this to my code to make it work?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go ahead with threads as below.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS

Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(fileReaderThread(), 0L, 300L, SECONDS)

  def fileReaderThread() = new Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      ReadFiles.main(Array("hdfs://.../info.log"))
    }
  }
```

Call newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor in a separate main only once. Later it will keep on calling your read files method in a fixed time.

Comment: Your suggestion solved my problem, thank you! However, is there a way for this reading to be infinite? When I close the command line, the reading is interrupted, and I just wanted it to stop when the class is deleted. Is there no way for the function to stay in the spark memory and continue processing?

Comment: Why not. So what you can do is submit your job in cluster mode or in nohup for background execution and have an infinite while loop and keep on checking for a showdown file at one location, use Thread.sleep(10000) and if file found call System.exit(0) else do nothing.

Comment: This solution really worked. But after 4 days, the function stopped updating the data every 5 minutes. Is it normal to happen? I wanted this to happen infinitely

Comment: Based on my experience it should not stop automatically.

Comment: I needed to stop this command, to delete everything he is saving and then run again. Is there a way to stop this command? It is inside the spark with connection to neo4j