# Running spark application as scheduled job

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

We have  written a program to fetch data from different sources, make modifications and write the modified data into a MySQL database. The program uses Apache spark for the ETL process, and makes use of **spark Java API** for this. Will be deploying the live application in Yarn or Kubernetes.

I need to run the program as a scheduled job, say with an interval of five minutes. Did some research and got different suggestions [including this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375571/running-scheduled-spark-job) from blogs and articles, like plain cron job, AWS glue, Apache Airflow etc for scheduling a spark application. From my reading, it seems I can't run my code (Spark java API) using AWS Glue as it supports only Python and Scala.
Can someone provide insights or suggestions on this? Which is the best option for running a spark application (in Kubernates or Yarn) as a scheduled job?
Is there an option for this in Amazon EMR? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I think and I used before is a `cronjob`, either :

- From inside your container with `crontab -e` with logging seting in case of failure such as:

```bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/spark/bin
40 13 * * * . /PERSIST_DATA/02_SparkPi_Test_Spark_Submit.sh > /PERSIST_DATA/work-dir/cron_logging/cronSpark 2>&1
```

- OR with a Kubernetes `Cronjob`, see here for different settings
  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/